# How to set camel quartz fire now option

Tags: apache-camel

I need to set firenow option in camel quatrz, so the process will start immediately when deployed, My process run every 15 minutes between 10PM to 8.55PM please see my config schedule below.

```
quartz2://processQuartz?cron=0+0/15+22-20+*+*+?
```

Please suggest how can start the first run immediately rather then waiting every 15 min period

Answer (score 0):

Try using startDelayedSeconds property.

```
<bean id="quartz" class="org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzComponent">
    <property name="startDelayedSeconds" value="0"/>
</bean>
```